# [AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower']

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
train = [('I love this sandwich.','pos'),
     ('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
     ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
     ('This is my best work.', 'pos'),
     ('What an awesome view', 'pos'),
     ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
     ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
     ("I can't deal with this.", 'neg'),
     ('He is my sworn enemy!.', 'neg'),
     ('My boss is horrible.', 'neg')
    ]
```

This is my training data and I'm using CountVectorizer but it is showing me error

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()
text_train_cv = cv.fit_transform(train)
text_train_cv.shape
```

Kindly please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `cv.fit_transform` method incorrectly. As per the documentation, this method accepts an *iterable of strings*. You are providing the method a list of tuples.

Here is an excerpt from the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform):

> **fit_transform**(*raw_documents, y=None*)
>   **Parameters: raw_documents**: iterable
>
> An iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects.

One way you can do this:

```
text_train_cv = cv.fit_transform(list(zip(*train))[0])
```

Comment: Thank u. it worked. But if i wanted to do preprocessing then??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. If you have a separate question, please ask it separately. If this helped, consider accepting (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Comment: Sir i mean to say that if I want to do pre_processing the data to clean the it. then how can I do that first? And how can I seperate positive and negative from list and get accuarcy using classifier?

Comment: @SikandarAli, These are all different questions. I don't know what you mean by "pre_processing" - is this a `sklearn` term? I've never heard it before. In fact, *I've never used `sklearn` before*, I'm just helping you fix your problem.

Comment: Oh!
preprocessing is use to clean the data by tokenize , remove stopwords and steming the data. then you further proceed to next step. By the way thank u soo much for your help :)

Comment: @SikandarAli. Ask as a separate question. I cannot help.

Comment: No problem sir :) Thank u for your time :)